# parse multiple date formats by index in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm trying to parse multiple date formats based on their position in a vector of dates. At some the data switched the format it used from y/m/d to y/d/m. This is annoying for dates like `2010/07/03` where specifying the order in lubridate .

This is an example of dates

```
datevec <- c("2011/07/01", "2011/07/02", "2011/07/03", "2011/02/07" )
```

The dates are set up so before a certain row the dates are one format and after another row the dates are another format, so I'm trying to provide an index to the function
when I tried to parse them using this plus `lubridate` it only returned 3 dates.

```
lapply(datevec, function(x, i) ifelse( x[i] <4,  parse_date_time(x, "%Y-%m-%d"), parse_date_time(x,"%Y-%d-%m" )) )
```

Comment: `lapply` only does one argument, so `i` is undefined in your anon-function. Further, I suspect that `x[i]` may be superfluous. What do you think should be happening there? `lubridate::parse_date_time(datevec, c("%Y-%m-%d", "%Y-%d-%m"))` worked for me.

Comment: BTW, if something earlier in the data pipeline is producing ambiguous dates like `2010/07/03` vs `2010/03/07` ... yeah, there's no code in the world that will *know* which format is appropriate. It's contextual, based on what you know of the process you own or have inherited, and possibly based on other cues in the data.

Comment: The data is set up so everything before a certain row is one format and everything after that row is another format. If I just specify the rows that have a certain format by their index (in this case <4) I can parse the dates correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** If we changed the ifelse in the question to a plain if then the basic idea  in the question works with appropriate modifications.  Note that it gives a list L so assuming we really want a vector we add the last line of code.

```
f <- function(x, i) if (i < 4) 
  parse_date_time(x, "ymd") else parse_date_time(x, "ydm")
L <- Map(f, datevec, seq_along(datevec), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
do.call("c", L)
## [1] "2011-07-01 UTC" "2011-07-02 UTC" "2011-07-03 UTC" "2011-02-07 UTC"
```

**2)** Use the ifelse on the format part rather than on the date part and use as.Date instead of parse_date_time:

```
ix <- seq_along(datevec)
as.Date(datevec, ifelse(ix < 4, "%Y/%m/%d", "%Y/%d/%m"))
## [1] "2011-07-01" "2011-07-02" "2011-07-03" "2011-07-02"
```

**3)** Convert the first 3 using ymd and the rest using ydm and then concatenate.

```
c(ymd(head(datevec, 3)), ydm(tail(datevec, -3)))
## [1] "2011-07-01" "2011-07-02" "2011-07-03" "2011-07-02"
```

**4)** or with only base R:

```
c(as.Date(head(datevec, 3)), as.Date(tail(datevec, -3), "%Y/%d/%m"))
## [1] "2011-07-01" "2011-07-02" "2011-07-03" "2011-07-02"
```

**5)** Another approach is to convert the later dates using string manipulation so that all the dates are in the same format and then use as.Date or ymd:

```
ix <- seq_along(datevec)
swap <- sub("(..)/(..)$", "\\2/\\1", datevec)
as.Date(ifelse(ix < 4, datevec, swap))
## [1] "2011-07-01" "2011-07-02" "2011-07-03" "2011-07-02"
```

**6)** The above codes return Date class, which is more appropriate for dates without times but if for some reason you really need POSIXct use as.POSIXct on the above or else use parse_date_time like this:

```
c(parse_date_time(head(datevec, 3), "ymd"), parse_date_time(tail(datevec, -3), "ydm"))
## [1] "2011-07-01 UTC" "2011-07-02 UTC" "2011-07-03 UTC" "2011-07-02 UTC"
```

Comment: When I ran this and checked the results with day() it returned `1 2 3 7` when it should be `1 2 3 2`

Comment: I have fixed it up but I didn't get what you report, I got a different wrong answer.  Anyways it should work now including fixing the approach in the question and fixing the original approach so that it works to use ifelse on the format rather than the data.

Comment: oh interesting what was the wrong answer that you got? Just curious because I want to debug to understand more

Comment: The original was parse_date_time(datevec, ifelse(seq_along(datevec) < 4, "ymd", "ydm")) but the problem with that is that it does not use the ith format with the ith datevec element but rather tries each format in turn. By switching to as.Date in (2) this is rectified.